# Converting words from camelCase to snake_case in C

Tags: c, computer-science

What I am trying to code is, if I input `camelcase`, it should just print out `camelcase`, but if there contains any uppercase, for example, if I input `camelCase`, it should print out `camel_case`.

The below is the one I am working on but the problem is, if I input, `camelCase`, it prints out `camel_ase`.

Can someone please tell me the reason and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char ch;
    char input[100];
    int i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        input[i] = ch;
        if (isupper(input[i])) {
            input[i] = '_';
            //input[i+1] = tolower(ch);
        } else {
            input[i] = ch;
        }
        printf("%c", input[i]);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an *`int`*. This is actually important for your check against `EOF`.

Comment: you *mean* `camelCase` (not ca**r**mel) and you confuse it with `snake_case`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First look at your code and think about what happens when someone enters a word longer than 100 characters -> *undefined behavior*. If you use a buffer for input, you *always* have to add checks so you don't *overflow* this buffer.

But then, as you directly print the characters, why do you need a buffer at all? It's completely unnecessary with the approach you show. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    int firstChar = 1; // needed to also accept PascalCase
    while((ch = getchar())!= EOF)
    {
        if(isupper(ch))
        {
            if (!firstChar) putchar('_');
            putchar(tolower(ch));

        } else
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        firstChar = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: I changed the type of `ch` to `int`. This is because `getchar()` returns an `int`, `putchar()`, `isupper()` and `islower()` take an `int` and they all use a value of an `unsigned char`, or `EOF`. As `char` is allowed to be signed, on a platform with signed `char`, you would get undefined behavior calling these functions with a negative `char`. I know, this is a bit complicated. Another way around this issue is to always cast your `char` to `unsigned char` when calling a function that takes the value of an `unsigned char` as an `int`.

---

As you use a buffer, and it's useless right now, you might be interested there *is* a possible solution making good use of a buffer: Read and write a whole line at a time. This is slightly more efficient than calling a function for every single character. Here's an example doing that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static size_t toSnakeCase(char *out, size_t outSize, const char *in)
{
    const char *inp = in;
    size_t n = 0;
    while (n < outSize - 1 && *inp)
    {
        if (*inp >= 'A' && *inp <= 'Z')
        {
            if (n > outSize - 3)
            {
                out[n++] = 0;
                return n;
            }
            out[n++] = '_';
            out[n++] = *inp + ('a' - 'A');
        }
        else
        {
            out[n++] = *inp;
        }
        ++inp;
    }
    out[n++] = 0;
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    char inbuf[512];
    char outbuf[1024]; // twice the lenght of the input is upper bound

    while (fgets(inbuf, 512, stdin))
    {
        toSnakeCase(outbuf, 1024, inbuf);
        fputs(outbuf, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This version also avoids `isupper()` and `tolower()`, but sacrifices portability. It **only** works if the character encoding has letters in sequence and has the uppercase letters before the lowercase letters. For ASCII, these assumptions hold. Be aware that what is considered an (uppercase) letter could also depend on the locale. The program above only works for letters A-Z as in the english language.

Comment: You can use `*inp ^ (1u << 5)` in place of `*inp + ('a' - `A')`. Each does the same thing, you're just toggling the case bit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- You insert one character in each branch of `if`, while one of them is supposed to insert two characters, and
- You print characters as you go, but the first branch is supposed to print both `_` and `ch`.

You can fix this by incrementing `i` on insertion with `i++`, and by printing the entire word at the end:

```
int ch; // <<== Has to be int, not char
char input[100];
int i = 0;

while((ch = getchar())!= EOF && (i < sizeof(input)-1)) {
    if(isupper(ch)) {
        if (i != 0) {
            input[i++] = '_';
        }
        ch = tolower(ch);
    }
    input[i++] = ch;
}
input[i] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
printf("%s\n", input);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/vjEwyv)

Comment: When I run the code that you wrote for me, it prints nothing.. how can I visualize the printf??

Comment: @seung I added a demo, it prints the expected string, please take a look.

Comment: OH thanks! but, as a last question, when I input an upper case for the first character, it makes it  underscore  as well, but I do not want the first character to be converted as '_'.. how should I resolve this problem?

Comment: @seung Add a check for `i != 0` to the condition.

Comment: tested with "LoremIpsumDolor" string

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: Off by one: `(i < sizeof(input)-1)` should be `(i < sizeof(input)-2)` to avoid potential buffer overflow in some cases such as a long sequence of uppercase letters..

Comment: How comes my comment is deleted? It's still true, OPs code has (at least) *three* problems, the buffer overflow is a very serious one. I think it should be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to code in C but I think you should do something like this.

```
if(isupper(input[i]))
{
    input[i] = tolower(ch);
    printf("_");

} else
{
    input[i] = ch;
}
```

Comment: This will put a lot of underscores to the beginning of upper-cased keywords, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `ch` is defined as a `char`: you cannot properly test for end of file if `c` is not defined as an `int`.  `getc()` can return all values of type `unsigned char` plus the special value `EOF`, which is negative. Define `ch` as `int`.
- You store the byte into the array `input` and use `isupper(input[i])`. `isupper()` is only defined for values returned by `getc()`, not for potentially negative values of the `char` type if this type is signed on the target system.  Use `isupper(ch)` or `isupper((unsigned char)input[i])`.
- You do not check if `i` is small enough before storing bytes to `input[i]`, causing a potential buffer overflow. Note that it is not necessary to store the characters into an array for your problem.
- You should insert the `'_'` in the array **and** the character converted to lowercase. This is your principal problem.
- Whether you want `Main` to be converted to `_main`, `main` or left as `Main` is a question of specification.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isupper(c)) {
            putchar('_');
            putchar(tolower(c));
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To output the entered characters in the form as you showed there is no need to use an array. The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            putchar('_');
            c = tolower(c);
        }
        putchar(c);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use a character array you should reserve one its element for the terminating zero if you want that the array would contain a string.

In this case the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char input[100];
    const size_t N = sizeof(input) / sizeof(*input);

    int c;
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i + 1 < N && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            input[i++] = '_';
            c = tolower(c);
        }
        if ( i + 1 != N ) input[i++] = c;
    }

    input[i] = '\0';

    puts(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off by one test: `i + 1 < N` -> `i + 2 < N`.

Comment: @chqrlie Why did you decide that there should be used I + 2 < N?

Comment: Because as written, you would have undefined behavior on a long string of uppercase letters ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie I have not understood why there will be undefined behavior.

Comment: if you have an uppercase letter when `i == N-2`, you will increment `i` twice and store the null byte into `input[N]`.